# .htaccess to act only on specific links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So, I need to rewrite a small HTML only website, so that it could work with multiple languages. I also want to keep the existing links operational, as not to hurt the ranking, and also, the original folder layout.

What I mean is, I am going to have a default language - lv. Then I, should have a RewriteRule that only works on .html links, and only, if there is either `(lv|en|ru)` between the first and the second slash, something like this:

```
http://example.com/lv/index.html
```

It should be routed to index.php, which would then get the language part out, if that is missing, it would check for a default value in session, and if that is missing - use default.

What I've been able to come up with is this:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]*)\.html $1.php
```

This works fine on the links, as it routes to the right page and with the right attribute, but it's not specific to my language needs, and also tries to reroute every other resource, because it contains no fallback. The fallback should be without the first segment, meaning, the language stripped out.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you are overengineering this.  You don't need to introduce a PHP script. What you are saying is that you have three language variants for HTML files, but that other extensions are common to all three languages.  So let's try again.  I am assuming that lv HTML live in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` hierarchy, but that you will have mirror hierarchies for English and Russian, so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

# If the request is for a language subdirectory: 
#  anything other than HTML or
#  the request is for the default lv
# then remove the language subdir

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !\.html\b
RewriteCond $1                =lv
RewriteRule ^(lv|en|ru)/(.*)  $2         [L]
```

Comment: But the site is quite image heavy. It also contains quite a lot of small html files. Therefore it seemed only logical to me, to use a single resource for every language, and leave the structure as it is. Easier to maintain, no?

Comment: Janis, if you want a crisp answer then its a lot easier if we don't have to discover your requirement by Q&A.  I assume therefore that its only the html files that you want a language variant for.  I'll update the ruleset in a moment.